# why is matplotlib surface plot looking like a line?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am having trouble getting matplotlib to plot this surface plot. This is the code flow I am using...

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')

x = np.arange(21)
y = np.arange(21)
xs, ys = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# My Z comes from other data and is 21 x 21 with values ranging from 300 -  500 forming a surface

ax.plot_surface(xs, ys, z)
plt.show()
```

I am getting an image which looks like this...

[image: matplotlib surface plot looks like line]

which looks like a line that doesn't span the whole space like my Z value does. What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

The answerers were right, it does work. In my applicatipn code I used the same array for x, and y as inputs to meshgrid which messed it up because I guess it needs to mutate them and function args are passed by reference

My Z for reference

```
[[380. 390. 400. 410. 419. 428. 436. 444. 451. 458. 465. 471. 477. 482. 488. 493. 497. 502. 506. 510. 513.]
 [390. 400. 410. 419. 428. 437. 445. 453. 461. 468. 474. 481. 487. 492. 497. 502. 507. 512. 516. 520. 523.]
 [399. 409. 419. 428. 437. 446. 455. 462. 470. 477. 483. 490. 496. 501. 506. 511. 516. 521. 525. 529. 532.]
 [407. 417. 427. 436. 445. 454. 462. 470. 478. 485. 491. 498. 503. 509. 514. 519. 524. 529. 533. 537. 540.]
 [413. 423. 433. 443. 452. 461. 469. 477. 484. 491. 498. 504. 510. 515. 521. 526. 531. 535. 539. 543. 547.]
 [419. 428. 438. 448. 457. 466. 474. 482. 489. 496. 503. 509. 515. 521. 526. 531. 536. 540. 544. 548. 552.]
 [423. 432. 442. 452. 461. 470. 478. 486. 493. 500. 507. 513. 519. 525. 530. 535. 540. 544. 548. 552. 556.]
 [426. 435. 445. 455. 464. 473. 481. 489. 496. 503. 510. 516. 522. 528. 533. 538. 543. 547. 551. 555. 559.]
 [428. 438. 448. 457. 466. 475. 483. 491. 499. 506. 512. 518. 524. 530. 535. 540. 545. 549. 554. 558. 561.]
 [430. 440. 449. 459. 468. 477. 485. 493. 500. 507. 514. 520. 526. 532. 537. 542. 547. 551. 555. 559. 563.]
 [431. 441. 451. 460. 469. 478. 486. 494. 502. 509. 515. 521. 527. 533. 538. 543. 548. 553. 557. 561. 564.]
 [432. 442. 452. 461. 470. 479. 487. 495. 503. 510. 516. 523. 528. 534. 539. 544. 549. 554. 558. 562. 565.]
 [433. 443. 452. 462. 471. 480. 488. 496. 503. 510. 517. 523. 529. 535. 540. 545. 550. 554. 559. 562. 566.]
 [433. 443. 453. 463. 472. 481. 489. 497. 504. 511. 518. 524. 530. 535. 541. 546. 550. 555. 559. 563. 566.]
 [434. 444. 454. 463. 472. 481. 489. 497. 504. 511. 518. 524. 530. 536. 541. 546. 551. 555. 560. 563. 567.]
 [434. 444. 454. 463. 473. 481. 490. 497. 505. 512. 518. 525. 531. 536. 541. 546. 551. 556. 560. 564. 567.]
 [434. 444. 454. 464. 473. 482. 490. 498. 505. 512. 519. 525. 531. 536. 542. 547. 551. 556. 560. 564. 567.]
 [435. 445. 454. 464. 473. 482. 490. 498. 505. 512. 519. 525. 531. 537. 542. 547. 552. 556. 560. 564. 568.]
 [435. 445. 454. 464. 473. 482. 490. 498. 505. 512. 519. 525. 531. 537. 542. 547. 552. 556. 560. 564. 568.]
 [435. 445. 455. 464. 473. 482. 490. 498. 505. 512. 519. 525. 531. 537. 542. 547. 552. 556. 561. 564. 568.]
 [435. 445. 455. 464. 473. 482. 490. 498. 506. 513. 519. 525. 531. 537. 542. 547. 552. 556. 561. 565. 568.]]
```

Comment: yes. typo. now fixed

Comment: Do you really use fig.subplot() ? I don't think this should work. Usual syntax is ax = fig.add_subplot(), or ax = plt.subplot()

Comment: you are correct, that was another typo. fixed. My code is in a bigger class so I had to type out the important parts by hand

Comment: If you still have a problem, it's probably coming from the way you load your data into `z`.
Could you show how you do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]`ax.plot_surface(x, y, z)` -> `ax.plot_surface(xs, ys, z)`

Comment: Hmm. Maybe the problem is that its a subplot or that I am redrawing it by just calling plot_surface again?

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me, z being an array filled with your data as such :

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d

z = np.array([[380., 390., 400., 410., 419., 428., 436., 444., 451., 458., 465., 471., 477., 482., 488., 493., 497., 502., 506., 510., 513.],
 [390., 400., 410., 419., 428., 437., 445., 453., 461., 468., 474., 481., 487., 492., 497., 502., 507., 512., 516., 520., 523.],
 [399., 409., 419., 428., 437., 446., 455., 462., 470., 477., 483., 490., 496., 501., 506., 511., 516., 521., 525., 529., 532.],
 [407., 417., 427., 436., 445., 454., 462., 470., 478., 485., 491., 498., 503., 509., 514., 519., 524., 529., 533., 537., 540.],
 [413., 423., 433., 443., 452., 461., 469., 477., 484., 491., 498., 504., 510., 515., 521., 526., 531., 535., 539., 543., 547.],
 [419., 428., 438., 448., 457., 466., 474., 482., 489., 496., 503., 509., 515., 521., 526., 531., 536., 540., 544., 548., 552.],
 [423., 432., 442., 452., 461., 470., 478., 486., 493., 500., 507., 513., 519., 525., 530., 535., 540., 544., 548., 552., 556.],
 [426., 435., 445., 455., 464., 473., 481., 489., 496., 503., 510., 516., 522., 528., 533., 538., 543., 547., 551., 555., 559.],
 [428., 438., 448., 457., 466., 475., 483., 491., 499., 506., 512., 518., 524., 530., 535., 540., 545., 549., 554., 558., 561.],
 [430., 440., 449., 459., 468., 477., 485., 493., 500., 507., 514., 520., 526., 532., 537., 542., 547., 551., 555., 559., 563.],
 [431., 441., 451., 460., 469., 478., 486., 494., 502., 509., 515., 521., 527., 533., 538., 543., 548., 553., 557., 561., 564.],
 [432., 442., 452., 461., 470., 479., 487., 495., 503., 510., 516., 523., 528., 534., 539., 544., 549., 554., 558., 562., 565.],
 [433., 443., 452., 462., 471., 480., 488., 496., 503., 510., 517., 523., 529., 535., 540., 545., 550., 554., 559., 562., 566.],
 [433., 443., 453., 463., 472., 481., 489., 497., 504., 511., 518., 524., 530., 535., 541., 546., 550., 555., 559., 563., 566.],
 [434., 444., 454., 463., 472., 481., 489., 497., 504., 511., 518., 524., 530., 536., 541., 546., 551., 555., 560., 563., 567.],
 [434., 444., 454., 463., 473., 481., 490., 497., 505., 512., 518., 525., 531., 536., 541., 546., 551., 556., 560., 564., 567.],
 [434., 444., 454., 464., 473., 482., 490., 498., 505., 512., 519., 525., 531., 536., 542., 547., 551., 556., 560., 564., 567.],
 [435., 445., 454., 464., 473., 482., 490., 498., 505., 512., 519., 525., 531., 537., 542., 547., 552., 556., 560., 564., 568.],
 [435., 445., 454., 464., 473., 482., 490., 498., 505., 512., 519., 525., 531., 537., 542., 547., 552., 556., 560., 564., 568.],
 [435., 445., 455., 464., 473., 482., 490., 498., 505., 512., 519., 525., 531., 537., 542., 547., 552., 556., 561., 564., 568.],
 [435., 445., 455., 464., 473., 482., 490., 498., 506., 513., 519., 525., 531., 537., 542., 547., 552., 556., 561., 565., 568.],])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')

x = np.arange(21)
y = np.arange(21)
xs, ys = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# My Z comes from other data and is 21 x 21 with values ranging from 300 -  500 forming a surface

ax.plot_surface(xs, ys, z)
plt.show()
```

[image: 3D plot]

If you still have a problem, it's probably coming from the way you load your data into `z`.